# Passar locais e coordenadas de uma UITableView para um MapKit

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, mapkit

Esta é a minha primeira App e, basicamente, consiste em disponibilizar locais numa UITable (ponto de entrada da app) e consultá-los numa MapKit (modelo StoryBoard). Como posso fazer a ligação?

Estou a tentar usar um NSDictionary para os valores na tabela e depois o método PrepareForSegue. É possível incluir coordenadas específicas no Dicionário ou num Array separado? E como especificar no método PrepareForSegue?

O código:

```
@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    _citySpots = @{@"Bars" : @[@"Hurricane", @"Black Swan", @"Texas"],
                       @"Clubs" : @[@"Electric Wizard", @"Offspring", @"The Tunnel"],
                       @"Restaurants" : @[@"Nando's", @"1/2 Burguer", @"Satellite"],
                       };

        _sectionTitles = [[_citySpots allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    }
```

O método PrepareForSegue:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"spotsDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        MapViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

        NSString *sectionTitle = [_sectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

         NSArray *citySpots = [_citySpots objectForKey:sectionTitle];
             //coordenadas?           

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode enviar o objeto pela `UISegue` pelo método `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    NSString *sectionTitle = [_sectionTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; // ou indexPath.section, eleja o correto
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SUA_SEGUE_AQUI" sender:sectionTitle];
}
```

E capturá-lo em `-prepareForSegue:sender:`:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id) sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SUA_SEGUE_AQUI"]) {
        MapViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSString *sectionTitle = (NSString *) sender;
        NSArray *citySpots = [_citySpots objectForKey:sectionTitle];
        destViewController.citySpots = citySpots;
    }
}
```